# Turn off display of remote laptop while in RDP session (win7)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, remote-desktop, screensaver

I have desktop computer (macos) and laptop (HP EliteBook 8460p, Win7), which being used almost remotely via RDP.
**The problem**: when RDP-connected, laptop's display always on and shows Windows login screen.

**Question**: how to turn laptop screen off while it's in RDP? Or is it possible to show screensaver?

What I tried:

1. Google said nothing to me. There is [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/566503/any-option-to-turn-off-laptop-display-when-i-remote-login-to-it-from-desktop) without answer.
2. I've tried to setup display while in RDP, but there is no access to real hardware display, and software RDP display activated.
3. I've tried to set screensaver, but in applying to "software" remote display, not to real.
4. I've tried to change display to external on laptop (fn buttons), but nothing happened.

So is it possible to turn off remote laptop display?

Comment: How about having the lid closed while RDP session into it? Maybe a simple solution like that and adjusting the power settings for telling it to not go to sleep when you close the screen and to only turn off the screen. I'm surprised you're RDP'ing into a laptop since it's portable but I understand regardless—gotta do what you gotta do. Try having the lid closed before you walk away from it for the day for a simple solution potentially and definitely simple enough to test. I assume it's not docked into a docking station with the power to the monitors off.

Comment: Thanks, @Facebook, that helped. Later I've rechecked power options and found, display turn off timeout was set to "never" if laptop not on battery. Now it turns off display as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there was misconfiguration of Power Options. The power plan was configured to never turn off display if plugged in.

Changing this to "10 minutes" solved the problem, display powers off in 10 minutes even if RDP-connected.

Path: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings\`